# Missing expected Identifier warning message

Tags: iphone

Getting red warning message that expected identifier for this statement

```
CALayer = ImageView.layer;
```

Using the above statement in the below code

```
// load all the frames of our animation
ImageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:    
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"2a.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"2b.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"2c.png"],
                             nil];

// all frames will execute in 28 seconds
ImageView.animationDuration = 28;
// start animating
[ImageView startAnimating];
[CALayer = [ImageView.layer]];
ImageView.layer.borderWidth = 2;
ImageView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor]CGColor];   
[ImageView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
[ImageView.layer setCornerRadius:15.0f];
[self.view addSubview:ImageView];
```

What i m missing here. Any ideas will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[CALayer = [ImageView.layer]];
```

Should be something like:

```
CALayer *myLayer = ImageView.layer;
```

Because you can't just assign to the class itself, you need an object of that class.
Also you don't need the brackets for assignment.

Comment: It should be like this CALayer *myLayer = ImageView.layer;
it worked. thanks

Answer (score 1):

1) It's an assignment, so the square brackets around it are wrong.

2) CALayer isn't a variable so you can't assign to it anyway.

3) The property reference `ImageView.layer` doesn't need square brackets either.

Comment: yeah i removed them but still getting the message

Comment: And did you also declare a variable for assigning the layer?  (In other words, what does your code **really** look like?)

Comment: UIImageView* ImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 300, 235)];

Comment: How's that related to the `CALayer` problem?